# ODBC ERROR [HY000] [TOD][ODBC][GENESIS]VISION: Cannot insert into 'STOCKTRN',No locks available

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, odbc

I send SQL command to ODBC to be able to insert into another application's database.

Looping in selected forms and its rows, I create command.

"OnTransactionCommand" simply returns an sql string of related row to be sent to ODBC for table 'STOCKTRN'

But the problem is that my integration function sometimes returns the error below:

```
ERROR [HY000] [TOD][ODBC][GENESIS]VISION: Cannot insert into 'STOCKTRN',No locks available
```

I am not sure but it is probably about the number of execution. With similar data when I test it with 15-20 records it works nicely. But Working with +50 records it returns error.

Is there any kind of limit or I am missing another part ?

My function:

```
private void MTransaction(MyGridView gvList)
{
    try
    {
        var m_Integration = ctx.Integration.Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
        if (m_Integration != null)
        {
            DbProviderFactory mFactory= DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(m_Integration.ServerType);
            using (DbConnection dbcon = mFactory.CreateConnection())
            {
                dbcon.ConnectionString = m_Integration.ConnString;
                for (int i = 0; i < gvList.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(gvList.GetRowCellValue(i, "Select")))
                    {
                        dbcon.Open();

                        int m_TransactionId = Convert.ToInt32(gvList.GetRowCellValue(i, "Id"));
                        MTransaction m_Transaction = ctx.Transaction.Where(c => c.Id == m_TransactionId).FirstOrDefault();

                        using (DbTransaction dbtr = dbcon.BeginTransaction())
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                using (DbCommand dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand())
                                {
                                    dbcmd.Transaction = dbtr;

                                    if (m_Transaction != null)
                                    {
                                        int TransactionRowCounter = 1;
                                        foreach (var item in m_Transaction.TransactionRow)
                                        {
                                            dbcmd.CommandText = OnTransactionCommand(m_Transaction, item, TransactionRowCounter);
                                            dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                                            TransactionRowCounter++;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    dbtr.Commit();
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception err)
                            {
                                dbtr.Rollback();
                                dbcon.Close();
                                XtraMessageBox.Show(err.Message);
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        dbcon.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        SuccessMessage = "Error:\n" + err.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to rule out your coding... Have you tried using more modern data access API's? Like OleDB or SqlClient?

Comment: I was asked to do so by the client. They were using that way with other apps.